# Having a hard time fixing the error, I'm still new to this

Tags: c++

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rationalsCN.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Carson;

int main() {
    Rational r1(3, 5);
    Rational r2(7);

    Rational r3;
    cout << "Enter a rational number in the format numerator/denominator: ";
    cin >> r3;

    cout << "r1 = " << r1 << endl;
    cout << "r2 = " << r2 << endl;
    cout << "r3 = " << r3 << endl;
 
    cout << "r1 == r2: " << (r1 == r2) << endl;
    cout << "r1 != r2: " << (r1 != r2) << endl;
    cout << "r1 < r2: " << (r1 < r2) << endl;
    cout << "r1 <= r2: " << (r1 <= r2) << endl;
    cout << "r1 > r2: " << (r1 > r2) << endl;
    cout << "r1 >= r2: " << (r1 >= r2) << endl;

    Rational sum = r1 + r2;
    Rational diff = r1 - r2;
    Rational prod = r1 * r2;
    Rational quotient = r1 / r2;

    cout << "r1 + r2 = " << sum << endl;
    cout << "r1 - r2 = " << diff << endl;
    cout << "r1 * r2 = " << prod << endl;
    cout << "r1 / r2 = " << quotient << endl;

    Rational zero;
    Rational divByZero(3, 0);
    Rational zeroByZero(0, 0);
    Rational zeroInNum(0, 3);
    Rational negNum(-3, 8);
    Rational negDenom(3, -8);
    Rational negBoth(-3, -8);

    cout << "zero = " << zero << endl;
    cout << "divByZero = " << divByZero << endl;
    cout << "zeroByZero = " << zeroByZero << endl;
    cout << "zeroInNum = " << zeroInNum << endl;
    cout << "negNum = " << negNum << endl;
    cout << "negDenom = " << negDenom << endl;
    cout << "negBoth = " << negBoth << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**RationsCN.h**

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Carson {
    class Rational {
        int num, denom;
        int gcd(int a, int b);
        void reduce();
        void initialize(int n, int d);
    public:
        Rational();
        Rational(int n);
        Rational(int n, int d);
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Rational& r);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Rational& r);
        friend bool operator==(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2);
        friend bool operator<(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2);
        friend bool operator<=(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2);
        friend bool operator>(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2);
        friend bool operator>=(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2);
        friend bool operator!=(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2);
        friend Rational operator+(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2);
        friend Rational operator-(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2);
        friend Rational operator*(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2);
        friend Rational operator/(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2);
        friend Rational operator-(const Rational& r);
    };
}

#endif
```

**RationalsCN.cpp**

```
#include "rationalsCN.h"

namespace Carson {
    int gcd(int a, int b) {
        return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}

namespace Carson {
    Rational::Rational(int numerator, int denominator) {
        if (denominator == 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Denominator can't be zero");
        }
        int divisor = gcd(numerator, denominator);
        num = numerator / divisor;
        denom = denominator / divisor;

        if (denom < 0) {
            num *= -1;
            denom *= -1;
        }
    }

    Rational::Rational(int numerator) : Rational(numerator, 1) {}
    
    Rational::Rational() : Rational(0, 1) {}

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Rational& r) {
        os << r.num << "/" << r.denom;
        return os;
    }

    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Rational& r) {
        int numerator, denominator;
        char slash;

        is >> numerator >> slash >> denominator;

        if (!is || slash != '/') {
            is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
            return is;
        }

        r = Rational(numerator, denominator);
        return is;
    }

    bool operator==(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2) {
        return r1.num == r2.num && r1.denom == r2.denom;
    }

    bool operator<(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2) {
        return r1.num * r2.denom < r2.num * r1.denom;
    }

    bool operator<=(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2) {
        return r1.num * r2.denom <= r2.num * r1.denom;
    }

    bool operator>(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2) {
        return r1.num * r2.denom > r2.num * r1.denom;
    }

    bool operator>=(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2) {
        return r1.num * r2.denom >= r2.num * r1.denom;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2) {
        return !(r1 == r2);
    }

    Rational operator+(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2) {
        int lcm = (r1.denom * r2.denom) / gcd(r1.denom, r2.denom);
        int num = (lcm / r1.denom) * r1.num + (lcm / r2.denom) * r2.num;
        return Rational(num, lcm);
    }

    Rational operator-(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2) {
        return r1 + Rational(-r2.num, r2.denom);
    }

    Rational operator*(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2) {
        return Rational(r1.num * r2.num, r1.denom * r2.denom);
    }

    Rational operator/(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2) {
        if (r2.num == 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("division by zero");
        }

        return Rational(r1.num * r2.denom, r1.denom * r2.num);
    }

    Rational operator-(const Rational& r) {
        return Rational(-r.num, r.denom);
    }
}
```

I'm getting these errors

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczoz2hS.o: in function Carson::Rational::Rational(int, int)':
rationalsCN.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to Carson::Rational::gcd(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've never gotten this error before, and it doesn't say what line it's on. I know it's in the rationalsCN.cpp, but I'm not sure what to change. Also I'm sure there are probably more efficient ways to do what I did.

Comment: That's a linker error. The linker often can't tell you what line the error is on because it's detected after the compiler is done and lines no longer exist.

Comment: `gcd` is declared as a member function of `Rational`. The one defined is `Carson::gcd`.  Typo ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You could have removed almost all of this code and still shown the problem. Also, nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Please see [ask] -- Your title is rather non-informative, and better questions tend to introduce the problem before posting any code.

Comment: Another useful link: [mre]. Even though the error message does not mention a line number, it does mention `Carson::Rational::Rational(int, int)` and `Carson::Rational::gcd(int, int)`. You should (make a copy of your code and) reduce your *example* code to those two functions, possibly plus a stub `main` function if necessary to preserve the error. The function bodies should be as short as possible -- `main` can define a `Rational` variable (to call the constructor `Rational::Rational`) and the constructor can call `gcd` but everything else is probably strippable. Just preserve the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) Specifically, the point "A common mistake is forgetting to qualify the name" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407).

Answer (score 0):

##### Four changes

I made four changes to get your program to compile.

1. Add include guard to file `RationsCN.h`. Presumably, your code has this already, but it did not get posted at SO.
2. Make `gcd` a static function of class `Rational`. At present, it is a member function. You may want to delete this function, in favor of [`std::gcd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd).
3. Scope the definition of function `gcd` to class `Rational` in file `RationsCN.cpp`.
4. Scope reference to function `gcd` to class `Rational` in function `operator+`.

Now it runs, but throws an exception when you call `gcd` in the constructor `Rational(int numerator, int denominator)`. I entered `3/4` for the test run.

##### Use a static function

```cpp
    class Rational {
        int num, denom;
        static int gcd(int a, int b);  // MAKE `gcd` A STATIC FUNCTION
        void reduce();
        void initialize(int n, int d);
    public:
    // ...
```

##### Scope the definition of function `gcd`

```cpp
namespace Carson {
    int Rational::gcd(int a, int b) {   // ADD SCOPE RESOLUTION
        return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

##### Scope reference to function `gcd` in friend function

```cpp
    Rational operator+(const Rational& r1, const Rational& r2) {
        int lcm = (r1.denom * r2.denom) / Rational::gcd(r1.denom, r2.denom);
        int num = (lcm / r1.denom) * r1.num + (lcm / r2.denom) * r2.num;
        return Rational(num, lcm);
    }
```

##### Suggestions

Writing class `Rational` is a great exercise for C++ students. Nice to see you take on the challenge.

Here are a few tips.

1. Use type `long long int`, rather than `int`. That gives you a bit more leg-room, before an extended series of calculations causes the denominator to blow up. I saw this when I used `Rational` as the element type in a matrix inversion program!
2. See [Comparing Rational Numbers Without Overflow](https://janmr.com/blog/2014/05/comparing-rational-numbers-without-overflow).
3. See the [Boost implementation of `operator+=`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/rational.hpp), for a few optimization tricks that will delay overflow.
4. Implement binary operators, such as `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`, in terms of their corresponding compound-assignment operators. For example:

```cpp
// Defined within class `Rational`, as a "hidden friend."
friend constexpr Rational operator+ (Rational lop, Rational const& rop)
{ 
    return lop += rop;
}
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

In RationsCN.h, `gcd` is a method of class `Rational` in namespace `Carson`.
In RationsCN.cpp, `gcd` is a function in namespace `Carson`.
Like Richard and JaMiT commented, the header will compile but there is no implementation of `Rational::gcd`.

The minimal change would be to remove the declaration of `gcd` from RationsCN.h. Only the cpp file would be able to access it. You could make it static too.

If you need `gcd` to be accessible by other classes, you could either:

- Update RationsCN.h to make `gcd` static. Update RationsCN.cpp to implement `Rational::gcd` rather than just `gcd`.
- Update RationCN.h only to make `gcd` a function outside of the `Rational` class but within the `Carson` namespace.